# Convert output from multiple t.tests to data frame

Tags: r

I have performed a t-test on all my rows in my data frame which outputs alot of p-values. How could I get out the p-values in data.frame format together with the row.name that was the basis for the test?

```
out2 <- apply(BindTissueSerumSort, 1, t.test, alternative = "greater")
```

All my p-values are stored in `out2` in the following formatting:

```
$`hsa-let-7a-5p.dataSerum`

    One Sample t-test

data:  newX[, i]
t = 10.747, df = 72, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.081222      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 1.279618
```

I would like to have something like:

```
rowname                      pvalue
$`hsa-let-7a-5p.dataSerum`   p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: We can use `v1 <- sapply(out2, function(x) x$p.value)` and `names(v1) < names(out2)` and if you need a data frame, `as.data.frame(v1)`  This gives the actual values, but if you need the string, use `paste`

Comment: thanks! you may provide it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `t.test` by row is a `list`.  So, we can use one of the methods to extract values from the list.  Either `sapply/lapply/vapply` can be used

```
v1 <- sapply(out2, function(x) x$p.value)
```

set the names of 'v1' as the names of the 'out2'

```
names(v1) < names(out2)
```

The above output is `vector`.  If we need a `data.frame`, wrap it with `as.data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(v1)
```